# Magento 2 website getting too much time to load

Tags: magento2, speedoptimization

Server - Freebsd Server (Ngnix)

Install Memcached + Redis + 8 GB ram

Website name - http://mastersdirect.masters-sp.com/shop/customer/account/login/

But still, site taking too much time to load can you please guide what is the missing part?

env.php file.

Please check below env.php config files

```php
 'session' => 
      array (
        'save' => 'memcached',
        'save_path' => '127.0.0.1:11211'
      ),
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'default',
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'vertex' => 1
    ],
    'install' => [
        'date' => 'Mon, 12 Dec 2016 18:24:29 +0000'
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'password' => ''
                ]
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'database' => '1',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'compress_data' => '0',
                    'password' => ''
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your site to production mode ?

Comment: Thanks for the response yes I tried with production mode also but did not impact so again switched back to the default mode

Comment: How many CPU cores?

Answer (score 1):

I checked this site in the console. I checked all JS(https://prnt.sc/oqhlv6).

http://mastersdirect.masters-sp.com/shop/pub/static/frontend/ASAD/masters/en_GB/tinyscrollbar.js this js taking around 5.1 sec and it goes to 403. Please remove this JS from your theme XML file to gain speed.

Comment: Thanks, Jeeva for the response, I have removed all js related issue from the page but still, web speed is not improved.
I have enabled profile for more information on the customer login page where Magento and layout node taking too much time to load.

http://mastersdirect.masters-sp.com/shop/customer/account/login/

Comment: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/mastersdirect.masters-sp.com/rEHrsdMO  .. Please perform these steps to improve the speed

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the response. Magento takes around 6 seconds to generate the page.
 [image: wow]

At first, check that production mode is enabled. Check the caches are enabled too. That account page is cacheable by default, but it doesn't seem like it uses cache to make a response, so maybe you have `cacheable="false"` somewhere that disables caching for the page.

Then try to install clean Magento 2 with sample data and measure the performance.

If clean Magento 2 works slow you need a better hosting. Otherwise, problem is related to your code customizations.

Try to disable some of your extensions, try to find a bottleneck using Magento 2 profiler. [Mgt Developer Toolbar](https://github.com/mgtcommerce/Mgt_Developertoolbar) is a **must have** tool for measuring performance.

I myself found a great guide on the Internet with lots of recommendations and advices. Pease, [check it here](https://onilab.com/blog/magento-2-performance-speed-optimization-guide/).

Comment: Thanks, Bitrixhater for the response, I have set up one more environment with the same configuration but loading time is still high.

Is there any missing configuration related to the server?

Website link - http://waytomsp.masters-sp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.

The issue in the PHP configuration previously I have installed mod_php changed to the FPM so the performance of the website is improved.

Thanks, everyone for the support.